# Android programatically add layout resource to view

Tags: java, android

I have a scrollview in an activity that I want to populate.  Each item I want to add to the list is made up of several views (text view, image view, etc).  Instead of programmatically creating each view, and adding it to a linear layout, and then adding that to the containing layout, is it possible to instead create a predefined layout resource with these items and instead add it to the view and programmatically change the item contents?

Essentially, is it possible to do something like:

```
container.addView(R.layout.listItem);
```

And if so, how could I access views within the list item to change them?

Comment: You can inflate the view resource and access views via the findViewById call. However I recommend using a RecyclerView.

Comment: you can inflate a layout also just like textviews in linear layout

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of views? If yes. Then you can use RecyclerView and then define your layout for a list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just what [inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) does with the third parameter `attachToRoot` set to true

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listItem, container, true);
```

After that everything is straightforward

```
container.findViewById(R.id.text_view)
```

Comment: What if I'm doing this in a loop and I want to findViewById for multiple instances?

Comment: Never mind, just figured it out by doing: View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_exercise, null);

view.findViewById ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to "inflate" your view by [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). For example like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listItem, container, true);
```

or 
`View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listItem, container, false);
container.addView(view);`